# SQL JOIN: Select records by joining two tables by an array of ids usin IN or ANY()

Tags: sql, postgresql

is it possible to join two tables using an array of ids in the first table?

### Example

**orders table**

```
create table orders
(
  id UUID DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
  user_id INT REFERENCES users (id),
  products_ids JSON NOT NULL,
  checkout_date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NOW()
);
```

**products table**

```
create table products
( 
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, -- some other columns 
)
```

###### *some records example*

orders table

| **id** | **user_id** | **products_ids** | **checkout_date** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0872ffb5-e347-447c-8b28-59368409cb84 | 1 | [1,2] | 1644863659550 |

products table

| id | title | other columns |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 'Lorem' |  |
| 2 | 'Ipsum' |  |

I want to join the two tables by products_ids like

```
SELECT * 
FROM orders AS o 
  INNER JOIN products AS p ON p.id = ANY(o.products_ids) 
WHERE o.usre_id = 1 
ORDER BY o.checkout_date
```

Comment: Possible? Sure. Efficient? Nope; it's gonna be as fast as a snail.

Comment: @TheImpaler I tried this code but isn't seems to be working

Comment: You’d better fix the real problem, your datamodel.

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags. Please tag a single database only.

Comment: @FrankHeikens can you explain a good strategy for the model?

Comment: `= any(...)` can only used with native arrays, not with JSON values. Also `1644863659550` is not a timestamp value

Comment: for the model, don't ever store arrays in columns, instead use a separate table.  it can just be (order_id, product_id).

Comment: @TheImpaler json_table makes this quite efficient, though postgres may not have that yet

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I know isn't a timestamp I just did it from the console and thanks for your replay

Comment: If the "console" is `psql`: that won't display `1644863659550` for a `timestamp` column.

Comment: @ysth: Postgres has `jsonb_each()` which is essentially the same as `json_table()` - but you don't even have to unnest the whole JSON array to check if a value is contained in it

Comment: @ysth This a non-normalized table that doesn't reach 1NF. For a query implementation to be efficient the index needs to accept multi-entries. A typical B-TREE index won't do. PostgreSQL implement GIST and GIN indexes that could fit the bill, but I don't think the OP wants to deal with all the impact of implementing them.

Comment: @TheImpaler I think you are reading the question differently than I am?  I think if they are selecting one order with two products and another order with three products they want 5 result rows, and there is no special form of index needed to join multiple products rows for each orders row.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name but the problem here is not checking if a value is contained in the json array, it is joining all product rows that are in the array.

Comment: @ysth: the check is needed for a join condition.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name not psql console but browser console 
its not matter cuz its just an example it should be in 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss' format.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name conceptually join conditions are non-directional, but practically speaking, most queries are going to be finding rows in one table that match the join condition for each selected row in another table.  and here, it will be finding products for each order

Comment: @ysth: well, in Postgres you _can_ have a join condition that tests if a value is contained in an array without turning the elements of the array into rows.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name right, and if they were finding orders with a certain product, that's what they would do (inefficiently, without a fixed model)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct solution is to properly normalize your data model and create a regular many-to-many relationship table.

---

However if you do want to go down the rabbit hole and use a de-normalized model, a native `int[]` array is slightly less bad than using a JSON column:

If `product_ids` is defined as `int[]` then indeed you can use the `=any(...)` operator:

```
select o.id, o.user_id, o.checkout_date, p.name
from orders o 
  join products p on p.id = any(o.product_ids);
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=69a7cc042289e6b7329c54359a5de5f0)

---

If you do insist on using JSON, then you can use a JSON/Path query to define the join condition:

```
select o.id, o.user_id, o.checkout_date, p.name
from orders o 
  join products p on jsonb_path_exists(product_ids, '$[*] ? (@ == $id)', jsonb_build_object('id', p.id))
```

Alternatively

```
select o.id, o.user_id, o.checkout_date, p.name
from orders o 
  join products p on o.product_ids @@ ('$[*] == '||p.id::text)::jsonpath
;
```

This assumes that `product_ids` is defined as `jsonb`, not a `json` column.

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=5c01b311cbed87d83777205e449b65b2)

---

But again: the **correct** solution is to use a properly normalized data model.

Comment: thanks, bro I appreciate that.

Comment: in the end, I create a new table for many to many relation, because what I'm trying to do is not the best practice.

Comment: @AbdelrhmanMohamed: good choice!

Answer (score 1):

In mysql, you use JSON_TABLE for this:

```
select orders.id, products.title from orders
join json_table(orders.product_ids,"$[*]" COLUMNS(product_id int path "$")) order_products
join products on products.id=order_products.product_id
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2fe194aa6b192efe477efd365ec59bc0

https://stackoverflow.com/a/61732970/17389 may show how to do this in postgres, but I don't know enough about postgres's json support to say how performant it will be.

Comment: thanks, bro I appreciate your time.