# How to Convert Oracle to Postgresql

Tags: json, oracle, postgresql-9.3

```sql
select row_number,tt.id
from test1,
     json_table(
       config_options,
       '$[]'
       columns(
         nested path '$.list[]',
         columns(row_number for ordinality),
         columns(id varchar2(100) path '$')
       )
     ) as tt;
```

I dont know how to convert.

Comment: Are you really still using Postgres 9.3? That is been unsupported [for 4 years now](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/). If you really plan to use JSON with Postgres, you should upgrade to the current version first.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/61731987/1509264